# What language is this (think it's Java?), and how do I test (using a browser ide) the math is correct in it?

Tags: java, math, solr

`div(1, sum(1, exp(sum(div(5, product(100, .1)), -5))))`

I'm using this in a Solr query, and want to verify that it is the same as :

[image: picture of sigmoid math equation]

Where x is 5.

1. Is this language Java?
2. If it is, why am I getting this output here:

http://ideone.com/LWYWtU

3. If it isn't, what language is this and how do I test it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: To add more of the surrounding code, here is the full `boost` value I'm sending to Solr:
`if(exists(query({!frange l=0 u=60 v=product(geodist(),0.621371)})),div(1, sum(1, exp(sum(div(product(5), product(100, .1)), -5)))),0)`

The reason I think it might be Java is because in the [docs](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery), it says `Most Java Math functions are now supported, including:` and then lists the math functions I ended up using for code.

Comment: That code snippet could be from a program written in any of hundreds of possible languages that all use a similar C type method-call syntax. Lack of a semicolon suggests either an incomplete statement or a non-Java statement.

Comment: The use of `product` suggests it's a functional language.

Comment: The static, non-operator calls suggest that it's not Java; unless someone has a library where for some reason they're creating their own math functions. I agree with @Hovercraft on both points. This probably isn't a descriptive enough snippet to definitely know the language.

Comment: @chrylis: I don't think that you can say even that. Any C-based syntax language would allow the coder to create a method called `product(double d1, double d2)` that would allow the exact syntax shown above.

Comment: If you're using that in a Solr query is it perhaps some DSL defined by Solr? What result are you getting from Solr?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, but nobody *would*.

Comment: Code snippet and equation are NOT the same. The equation contains a variable 'x' but the code does not contain such a variable.

Comment: @FredK see the line right below the equation?

Comment: Instead of trying to figure out if Solr is Java, just read the documentation for the other functions you have and make sure they do what you want them to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr is Java, but that's not relevant since this is a set of functions that Solr parses and evaluate itself (and not related to Java, except that the backing functions are implemented in Java).

As far as I can say from what you've mapped the functions correctly, as long as the `5` in `product(5)` is the same as X. You shouldn't need `product` there, as the value can be included in `div` directly as far as I can see.

A way to validate it would be to use `debugQuery` in Solr and see what the value is evaluated as, and then compare it to your own value. Remember that floating point evaluation can introduce a few uncertanities.